# React MaterialUI - How to disable ripple effect for Select element

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

[image]

When I click the `Select` element, I would like to disable the blue bottom bar in the `Select` element in React Material UI.

I tried the following but not working:

```
import { withStyles, Select } from "@material-ui/core";

export default withStyles({
  // Override default CSS for input
  root: {
    "& .MuiInput-underline": {
      // Remove the ripple effect on input
      "&:after": {
        borderBottom: "initial",
      },
    },
  },
})(Select);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please pass `disableUnderline` as a prop in the Select component

Comment: I just want to keep the gray underline, just not the blue underline shown by clicking it.

Comment: simply add a style with `disableUnderline` ? `style={{ borderBottom: "2px solid grey" }}` also it will not have any ripple effect which you don't want it?